# Iframe allowfullscreen not working for dailymotion video

Tags: html, iframe

I want to show full screen option in `<iframe>` for dailymotion video.
I have tried this one

```
<iframe id="vid_frame" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2rbh2c" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" oallowfullscreen="true" msallowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="260"></iframe>
```

But fullscreen option is not showing .Same code working for youtube video.

Comment: You can try with html5 code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can also try in online..**

The script of dailymotion site is not get access for show full screen.

You can see in JavaScript console.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That works

```
<iframe webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
```